# Running a crontab on docker container not running?

Tags: docker, cron

On my host machine I have the following crontab command:
`* * * * * /usr/bin/docker exec container_name rm /tmp/*.txt`

Yet when I log into the container via `docker exec container_name bash` and view the contents of the /tmp dir I see all the .txt files. When I am logged in and manually run this rm command all .txt files are cleared out of /tmp.

My other crontab's running on the container are working.

What could cause this not to work?

Comment: The commands you run via cron is different from what you do by running `bash` which requires a terminal. 

Instead, an easier way is to execute a container:script.sh from the host machine via cron which does the same or have you tried with quotes: 
```/usr/bin/docker exec container_name /bin/sh -c "rm /tmp/*.txt"```

Comment: I haven't tried that yet. I'll try it and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregating the answer from my comment:

The commands you run via cron is different from what you do by running bash which requires a terminal. Instead, an easier way is to execute a container:script.sh from the host machine via cron which does the same or

You can try the same with quotes:

```
#crontab 
/usr/bin/docker exec container_name /bin/sh -c "rm /tmp/*.txt"
```